# Using Polymaps with Cloudmade and Android

Tags: javascript, android, svg, maps, gis

We are trying to use Polymaps and have a few questions about it:

1. It seems to make calls to Cloudmade to get the map images. Does Cloudmade provide these images for free forever? Are these freely downloadable?
2. If we wanted to replace the source of map images from Cloudmade to Tilemill, is that a possibility?
3. Also, Polymaps uses SVG, does this mean the maps will not display on Android 2.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding question 1, tiles are $25/million and the first 500k in each calendar month are free.  So for an app getting off the ground it is effectively free.  You will need your own apikey and should experiment with getting the styles you want in the style editor.

Comment: You shouldn't sign your answer. Use your profile to put information instead.